# Populate template with data on page load

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to populate a html page with user's profile details on page load. Django document has this  `get_context_data()` method in TemplateView, when I am using the same to display data to html page I get the following exception

```
TemplateDoesNotExist(', '.join(template_name_list), chain=chain)
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: app/profile.html
```

Here is my code:

*urls.py*

```
url(r'^profile/', views.ProfileDetailView.as_view(), name='profile'),
```

*views.py*

```
class ProfileDetailView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "appName/profile.html"
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        if 'user_name' in self.request.session:          
            username = self.request.session['user_name']                        
            return render_to_response('appName:profile', {'username': username})
```

This is how am using in the html page

*profile.html*

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="User name" id="usernameDisplay" name="usernameDisplay" readonly  value="{{ username }}">
```

Where am I going wrong?

**Edit1:**

*settings.py*

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**P.S:** All other templates are working fine the problem lies only with this one which I am trying to populate with data on page load.

**Edit 2:**
There was some naming issue the exception now is:

```
 TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: appName:profile
```

Comment: can you show ur settings.py file

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: Where is you template folder? in App or project level?

Comment: @ans2human Inside appName -> templates-> appName- > .html files

Comment: @Jagruti, ok and  Whats the application name?

Comment: @ans2human It's appName the same I have mentioned in the question

Comment: Can you check your settings.py for TEMPLATES directory path ? as suggested by @c.grey in answers

Comment: @DeepamPatel It did not help. My all other templates are working fine. But this one when I am trying to load the template with data

Comment: @Jagruti was your problem resolved?

Comment: @ans2human No. I have suspended it for today. Will try again tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

please check your TEMPLATES_DIRS properly

DIRS defines a list of directories where the engine should look for template source files, in search order.

in your settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {

      'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],

    },
]
```

hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

it seems your app looks for `profile.html` in `app` folder. So here's how the directory should look.

In your `appName` folder create a `templates` folder and the create a folder inside it with your "appName". I'm sure this folder is named `app`. Rectify it to the `appName`.

```
[projectname]/                  <- project root
├── [projectname]               <- Django root
│  
├── appName/
|       | 
|       |── templates/
|                ├── appName
|                       └── Profile.html
|                  
│     
├── manage.py
```